# Hover a form over an image HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I get this form over the image and make it fit?

http://insightcxo.com/landing-test/

Thanks all.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qd08sydx/9/ here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work for you.

```
#sidebar {height:350px;
    width:auto; 
    background-image: url("http://www.insightcxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/blog-form-background1.png");
    background-size:cover;

}
```

If it's too close to the side, add a margin-right as you see fit.

EDIT:

Here are the changes I made to your main style.css in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd08sydx/10) to make your input fields appear correctly:

I added the css

```
#inf_field_FirstName {
margin-top:200px; /*this line*/
width: 330px;
text-align: center;
}

label.FName{margin-top:200px!important;} /*I created this label class*/
```

I added the class Fname to your First name label. Voila!

Comment: Almost worked! It's actually for a sidebar widget - don't know why I had the page url up there.

But this is what it looks like now

http://insightcxo.com/eliminate-the-fear-of-focus/

Comment: so just change the body to #sidebar and specify your desired width and height - you could even do width:auto; height:auto;

Comment: I changed the width/height from 100% to auto but it's not working. :(

Comment: set the height to about 350px and leave the width at auto

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qd08sydx/1/

Comment: It's super close!

http://insightcxo.com/eliminate-the-fear-of-focus/

just need to move the input fields down.

Comment: you could set a margin-right to 10px or so

Comment: Bah! Still didn't work :( I have to go but I'll try to fix this later.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could take the image an set it via css as background-image of the tabele.

Comment: do you know the css code to make it the background? I've tried it and it's not working. 

   .body {
    background-image: url("http://insightcxo.com/wp-   content/uploads/2015/07/blog-form-background1.png");
    
   }

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using text (or at least meaningful copy) in images. Screen readers can't render it and it won't contribute to any keywords you might find handy for SEO reasons. In terms of the fix, remove the fake text from the image, set the image as a background image of the form container (sorry, can't inspect your code as on phone), then add a paragraph containing the image text about the form...

Comment: Hi eAgobe - ya I know but that's what the owner wants. It's the font he really likes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `background-image`, and it doesn't work. If you *actually* want to get it over the image, add these:

```
img.aligncenter.size-full.wp-image-1012{
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px; <-- to keep the same distance, alter if you want to   
}

table.bodyContainer.webFormBodyContainer{
    position: relative;
    top: 170px;
}
```

I mean, I did get it over the top:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVI9j.jpg

Yeah...since the background of the form is always going to be white, if you want to place it over the image, it's gonna stand out and mess up the image gradient. I can't help you at that. It's the closest I got.